# -webkit-border-radius does not crop image properly

Tags: html, css

I have 5 browsers for rendering html coded pages: IE9, Firefox 4.0 and all the newest versions of Chrome, Safari and Opera. Now in IE9 and Firefox 4.0 an image is being cropped properly in using border-radius: and -moz-border-radius: but fails in Opera, Chrome and Safari using -webkit-border-radius:. With Opera the image is not being cropped at all and with Safari and Chrome the image is somewhat cropped but with the border being cropped out as well.

```
.nonTyp{
margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
border:4px inset #C1C8DD;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
-webkit-border-radius:25px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
```

}

If you have one of the 3 browsers mentioned that utilize -webkit-border-radius: please view images for example of what I have an issue with:
[Graphics Page](http://www.wa-state-outdoors.com/e-portfolio/graphics.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is put all styling that's on the `<img>` tag now, on the parent `<a>` instead so as to use it as the container for the image. This, at least to me, makes more sense as well. Don't forget to keep `float: left` on the image to get rid of phantom bottom margin either.

Comment: I have this declared in the css: a img{ ; then with the same border radius syntax needed for rendering a border radius, but nothing seems to be working. The 3 browsers (Safari, Chrome and Opera) are the only ones that are having this issue, IE9 and Firefox 4.0 work fine.

Comment: I changed the all stylings in the <a> tag and still does not render properly, going to shoot a few emails to Safari and Google about this and see what they have to say, thanks to all on this issue.

Comment: good job on this workaround for this issue, your example works pretty dang good just need to set some styling issues (mainly the hot-pink border....lol), thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @Matijs, what if I want to use the `position: relative` on the `img`?

Comment: @RevoltEr on its own or were you going to do something with `left, right, top, bottom` as well?

Comment: @Matijs, Yes, I wanted to use `left` position on `:hover` but I solved it with jQuery.

Comment: @RevoltEr sounds like something you should be doing with CSS, not JavaScript. You could use an `a:hover > img` be better for targeting this.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because it is in the foreground above the border

try using the same code you have above, but in your html:

```
<div class="nonTyp" style="background-image:url('image.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: That would be creating container areas for every img. I have done this to show how to correct this issue, but would like to know if -webkit-border-radius: bug is being fixed.

Comment: <a href="images/non-typical-1.jpg" title="Click to see large image" onClick="Expand('images/non-typical-1.jpg', 600, 600); return false;" rel="nofollow"><img class="nonTyp" src="images/non-typical-1.jpg" alt="Non Typical" /></a>

Comment: `<a href="images/non-typical-1.jpg" title="Click to see large image" onClick="Expand('images/non-typical-1.jpg', 600, 600); return false;" rel="nofollow"><div class="nonTyp" style="background-image:url('images/non-typical-1.jpg');"></div></a>` you can still hyperlink containers as long as they have width and height. what do you mean by "if -webkit-border-radius: bug is being fixed."?

Comment: I mean that when you use a -webkit-border-radius on a <img> it will not render properly in Opera, Chrome and Safari. You will notice that I have declared a class= for the image which is defined in a external stylesheet, which also declares width and height. The syntax is correct for all browsers and renders like it should in Firefox 4.0 and IE9. The only workaround that I can figure to use is creating a div container and using background-image: which will render border radius properly. -webkit-border-radius for <img> is the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with the order in which the border vs. radius clip is applied, but is very strange. A solution is to move the border-radius and related definitions to the enclosing  tag. Remember to declare `display:block` so it's treated as block level on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Chrome and Safari.

Image is top level.

`div.someclass` with radius 5px and `div.someclass` img with radius 4px.

That seems to make the corners look cleaner in Chrome and Safari.

```
.someclass {
  ...
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
          border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000; 
}

.someclass img {
  ...
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
          border-radius: 4px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think drawing functions that Chrome uses for image and link are works differently between each other. And that causes a blank space between image and the link.

I partially fixed this bug via modifying Matjis' jsfiddle code a little bit. I moved img  tags position to left.

```
.gallery a img {
...
position:relative;
left: 2px;
}
```

This solution may work if you set different radius values for image and the link.